# what is the best open source tools for develop AR app?

Tags: android, open-source, opengl

I am a beginner in augmented reality. I want to create an Augmented Reality app that allows the user to sign up and tell the user by location what nearby restaurants are, and the user can visually see restaurants on the mobile screen. It also allows the user to visualize the three-dimensional image on a paper page, for example, a three-dimensional story book. As well as qr code. In fact, I want to create an app that is based on a location and based on a marker. I do not want to use tools that license, because they are limited and the user has to download their app first. I want to develop my own application. And use open source tools (artoolkit, droidar, beyound, mixare,arlab). I've also read that opencv is also used for augmented reality. Which of these tools is better and easier to develop for Augmented Reality App. Please guide me because I'm new. Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: did you achieve your goal? Do you recommend any sdk?